# Alexa notifications: The authentication token is not valid

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-notification

Is Alexa notifications are available for dev skills? I'm not seeing any configuration anywhere. I'm getting this error when sending notification.

```
{
    "message": "The authentication token is not valid.",
    "code": 403
}
```

Comment: How did you send the notifications?

Comment: From the skill itself. In launch request.

Comment: which is the API you are hitting

Comment: api.amazonalexa.com//v2/notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, Notifications feature in the Alexa Skills Kit is not generally available. Anyone who wants to have notifications feature has to fill [**this**](https://alexa.au1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_72lplGGegxNZ9Ln) survey and Amazon team provides more information if they think the skill is qualified to have notifications feature. For more information see **[this](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/173179/how-to-push-notification-to-alexa-from-custom-skil.html)**